# Django template tag to show null date as "still open"

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following code in a Django template:

```
{{date_from|date:"Y-m"}} - {{date_to|default_if_none:"still open"|date:"Y-m"}}
```

I currently get:

1. "2012-08 - "
2. "2012-11 - 2012-08"
3. .. rest of values that are correctly displayed.

I would like to get to this:

1. "2012-08 - still open"
2. "2012-11 - 2012-08"
3. .. rest of values that are correctly displayed.

Do you have any suggestions?
I think it is not displayed properly because it is a date object.

Comment: Have you tried to change filter order to `{{date_to|date:"Y-m"|default_if_none:"still open"}}` ? ( have more sense )

Comment: Yes, but as falsetru said, I had to use default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the order of filters. Use `default` instead of `default_if_none` (`date` filter will return empty string for non-date/datetime object)

```
>>> t = Template('{{date_to|date:"Y-m"|default:"still open"}}')
>>> t.render(Context({'date_to': None}))
u'still open'
>>> t.render(Context({'date_to': datetime.datetime.now()}))
u'2014-04'
```

Comment: It now works as expected. Thank you also for the explanation behind the logic.